directus - how to filter a many to one field based on the value of another many to 1 field
In directus - I have a field 'street' that I want to populate based on a field 'city' that is chosen.
How can this be done ?
This is so basic , and strange that I need to search for hours how to do it
Of course the city has the values title, id , new id
The street has the values name, id , city id.
what I present in the fields is name, but the filtering is by id
I tried doing something like this:
{
    "_and": [
        {
            "city_id": {
                "_eq": "{{city.new_id}}"
            }
        }
    ]
}

and like this :
{
    "city_id": {
        "_eq": "{{city.new_id}}"
    }
}

but it did not work.
Thanks a lot.
